# Is it okay to write KVL equations like this (using complex numbers)?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

> For the circuit shown in the figure, determine the value of \$V_2\$
>   such that current through \$5\Omega\$ resistance is \$0\$.

[image]

**My attempt:**

Let current in left loop be \$I_1\$, middle loop be \$I_2\$ and right loop be \$I_3\$ (all three are clockwise). So the KVL equations I get are:

$$+20e^{j(0)} - 4I_1 - 3jI_1 + 3j I_2 = 0$$

$$-3jI_2 + 3j I_1 - 3I_2 - 4jI_2 + 5jI_2 - 5j I_3 = 0$$

$$5j I_3 - 5j I_2 - 5 I_3 -V_2 =0 $$

I intend to put \$I_3=0\$, since current in the \$5\Omega\$ resistor should be \$0\$. Then I should get a complex number value for \$V_2\$, by solving the three simultaneous equations. But I'm not sure whether this techniques is correct. I've never written KVL equations like these (using complex impedances). Could someone please tell me if there is any error in my method? Or is it okay?

Comment: Your second equation has 5/j where the diagram has 5j. That will change your answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton \$5/j = - 5j\$. I wrote that that way to denote the drop in potential after current \$I_2\$ passes through it, in clockwise direction. I guess that term can be equivalently written as +\$5jI_2\$, in the equation. (The main reason being impedance of capacitor is negative and generally written as \$1/jwC\$)

Comment: OK, if you worked it out it's okay. But it's a bit confusing for anybody reading it because everywhere else you just used "-j" to mean -j.

Comment: @ThePhoton I changed that now. Apart from that does the method look legitimate ?

Comment: I haven't checked all your signs, but yes, this is exactly how you solve AC circuits. You use KVL or KCL with the complex impedance values of the circuit components.

Comment: @ThePhoton Got it. Thanks a lot for your feedback!